# Extract Lotus Notes attachments using VBA

Tags: vba, lotus-notes

I need to use VBA to pull in attachments to Excel that are mailed daily to my Lotus Notes account.

Let me know if this is at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly, take a look at the [NotesEmbeddedObject](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESEMBEDDEDOBJECT_CLASS.html) class. [More info](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_WORKING_WITH_EMBEDDED_OBJECTS_LOTUSSCRIPT.html) about dealing with attachments in Domino.